# Elemento se crea pero no aparece renderizado

Tags: javascript

Estoy haciendo un codigo para crear cuestionarios personalizados. Lo que se puede hacer actualmente con lo que he programado es modificar la pregunta, ingresar el texto para una respuesta y añadir el boton de radio, sin embargo el texto del boton de radio no aparece solo el radio, ese es el problema con el que me estoy enfrentando actualmente. Lo unico que quiero lograr por el momento es que se puede agregar un solo boton de radio, luego hare un ciclo para crear id necesarias para los elementos que lo necesiten.

```js
  function editar(){
   document.getElementById("pregunta").style.display = "none";
   document.getElementById("nPregunta").style.display = "block";
   document.getElementById("boton1").style.display = "block";
   var predeterminado = document.getElementById("pregunta").innerHTML;
   document.getElementById("nPregunta").value = predeterminado;
  }
  function modificar(){
   var nuevaPregunta = document.getElementById("nPregunta").value;
   document.getElementById("pregunta").innerHTML = nuevaPregunta;
   document.getElementById("pregunta").style.display = "block";
   document.getElementById("nPregunta").style.display = "none";
   document.getElementById("boton1").style.display = "none";
   if(document.getElementById("nPregunta").value == ""){
    document.getElementById("pregunta").innerHTML = "Escribe una pregunta";
   }
  }
  function nuevaRespuesta(){
   document.getElementById("nRespuesta").style.display = "block";
   document.getElementById("boton2").style.display = "block";
  }
  function agregarRespuesta(){
   var nuevaRespuesta = document.getElementById("nRespuesta").value;
   document.getElementById("nRespuesta").style.display = "none";
   document.getElementById("boton2").style.display = "none";
   console.log(nuevaRespuesta);
   var input = document.createElement("INPUT");
   input.id = "r";
   input.type = "radio";
   var radioTexto = document.createTextNode(nuevaRespuesta);
   input.appendChild(radioTexto);
   document.getElementById("opciones").appendChild(input);
   document.getElementById("r").style.display = "block";
  }
```

```css
input{
  display: none;
 }
 button{
  display: none;
 }
```

```html
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
 <h3 id="pregunta" onclick="editar()">Hola :)</h3>
 <div id="opciones"></div>
 <input id="nPregunta">
 <button id="boton1" onclick="modificar()">listo</button> <!-- -->
 <input id="nRespuesta" placeholder="escribe una respuesta">
 <button id="boton2" onclick="agregarRespuesta()">listo</button>
 <p onclick="nuevaRespuesta()">añadir respuesta</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

La cuestión es que a un `input` tipo `radio` no le puedes agregar un texto como tal, por lo tanto debe de ser acompañado de un `<label> o <p>` para que indiques que contexto tiene ese `input`, solamente creo un `<label>` le agrego un texto y dentro del `<label>` agrego el radio, cualquier duda hazla saber.

```js
function editar(){
   document.getElementById("pregunta").style.display = "none";
   document.getElementById("nPregunta").style.display = "block";
   document.getElementById("boton1").style.display = "block";
   var predeterminado = document.getElementById("pregunta").innerHTML;
   document.getElementById("nPregunta").value = predeterminado;
  }
  function modificar(){
   var nuevaPregunta = document.getElementById("nPregunta").value;
   document.getElementById("pregunta").innerHTML = nuevaPregunta;
   document.getElementById("pregunta").style.display = "block";
   document.getElementById("nPregunta").style.display = "none";
   document.getElementById("boton1").style.display = "none";
   if(document.getElementById("nPregunta").value == ""){
    document.getElementById("pregunta").innerHTML = "Escribe una pregunta";
   }
  }
  function nuevaRespuesta(){
   document.getElementById("nRespuesta").style.display = "block";
   document.getElementById("boton2").style.display = "block";
  }
  function agregarRespuesta(){
   var nuevaRespuesta = document.getElementById("nRespuesta").value;
   document.getElementById("nRespuesta").style.display = "none";
   document.getElementById("boton2").style.display = "none";
   console.log(nuevaRespuesta);
   var input = document.createElement("INPUT");
   input.id = "r";
   input.type = "radio";
   //var radioTexto = document.createTextNode(nuevaRespuesta);
   //input.appendChild(radioTexto);
      var label = document.createElement('label');
      var text = document.createTextNode(document.getElementById("nRespuesta").value);
      label.appendChild(text);
      label.appendChild(input);
   document.getElementById("opciones").appendChild(label);
   document.getElementById("r").style.display = "block";
  }
```

```css
input.r{
  display: none;
 }
  input{
  display: none;
 }
 button{
  display: none;
 }
```

```html
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
 <h3 id="pregunta" onclick="editar()">Hola :)</h3>
 <div id="opciones"></div>
 <input id="nPregunta">
 <button id="boton1" onclick="modificar()">listo</button> <!-- -->
 <input id="nRespuesta" placeholder="escribe una respuesta">
 <button id="boton2" onclick="agregarRespuesta()">listo</button>
 <p onclick="nuevaRespuesta()">añadir respuesta</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Estas creando un nuevo elemento DOM, el *input* de tipo *checkbox*, pero no un elemento textual que le acompañe, un *label* por ejemplo. El texto no es un elemento hijo del *checkbox*.

Las siguientes dos líneas de tu código no tienen efecto:

```
var radioTexto = document.createTextNode(nuevaRespuesta);
input.appendChild(radioTexto);
```

básicamente porque un *input* no tiene elementos hijos. Es posible hacerlo en sentido opuesto, es decir añadir el *input* dentro del *label*. La siguiente estructura, por ejemplo:

```
<label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="value">
    Text
</label>
```

si que se renderizará correctamente.